# How do you determine the height of a mesh above the xy-plane?

Tags: mesh, measurement

[image: Picture for Reference]

Hello everyone! I am a very new to blender, and I was wondering how I could determine the height of the portion of a mesh that is strictly above the xy-axis? I have included the image, as well as the height I am looking for above. For context, I am making 3d models of dice, and I have extruded numbers that I will be using for the faces. The numbers will overlap with the mesh about 1 meter deep into the face, and then using a boolean difference action I will cut out the number from the dice. I want to be as precise with the pip as possible, so figuring out this height "h" would be extremely helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello :). Every vertex has a precise x,y,z, location. Above XY plane it's the +Z value. Use edit mode to select individual vertices.

Comment: There is also a ruler in the left menu that you could use

Comment: It's rather easy here, it's the z coordinate of vertex that has the biggest z coordinate.